# 外部HDDがマウントされているのに表示されない

Tags: linux

Linux Mint 18.3 Sylviaの環境です。

USB接続の外部HDD（元はNTFS）をext4にフォーマットしなおして
使おうとしています。

現状、`parted`を使用してパーティションを作成し、`mkfs.ext4`を使って
フォーマットまで行いました。

デフォルトでは`/media/[username]`にマウントされていますが、
これを変えようとして

```
$ sudo umount /dev/sdb1
$ sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/[username]
```

としたところ、`/mnt/[username]`にデバイスが表示されませんでした。
このようになった原因について教えていただけますでしょうか？

以下、参考情報です：
①partedで作成したパーティション情報

```
(parted) p                                                                
モデル: StoreJet Transcend (scsi)
ディスク /dev/sdb: 1000GB
セクタサイズ (論理/物理): 512B/512B
パーティションテーブル: gpt
ディスクフラグ: 

番号  開始    終了    サイズ  ファイルシステム  名前       フラグ
 1    1049kB  1000GB  1000GB  ext4              Transcend
```

②`/mnt/[username]`にマウントしたあとのマウント状況

```
$ sudo mount
$ /dev/sdb1 on /mnt/[username] type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
```

③`mnt/[username]`での`ls`

```
/mnt/[username] $ ls -l
合計 16
drwx------ 2 root root 16384 12月  2 12:38 lost+found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/mnt/[username]`にHDDのパーティションをマウントしたのであれば、`/mnt/[username]`を開いて表示されるのはHDDの**中身**(データ)であり、デバイスは表示されません。
`mount`や`ls`コマンドの実行結果を見る限り、マウント自体は特に問題ないように見えます。

**追記**
「ラベルが表示されない」ということであれば、パーティションをフォーマットし直した時点で元々のラベルは削除されていると思うので、改めてラベルを設定し直す必要があると思います。

```
$ sudo e2label /dev/sdb1 extHDD
```

Comment: 回答有り難うございます。OSの方で自動マウントする際はラベル名がフォルダとして表示されますが、/mnt/[username]を指定するような場合はラベル名はフォルダにはならず、中身だけが表示されるということでしょうか？